# How to print Reportviewer without a Preview

Tags: c#, report

Im new to the c#, currently Im making a `POS` application witch can **print a Receipt**. I used **reportviewer** component for create the Receipt. I is working. but I couldn't pass the print command directly. When it is preview I have to press `Print Button manually.` but I need to print it automatically `without a preview.` here is my beginning of the code.  Is there any way to bind this `repotviewr` with `PrintDocument` or how can I print this `reportviewer` automatically

> Open FormReceipt

```
DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;
            FormReceipt frmReceipt = new FormReceipt(order, String.Format("{0:n}", totalAmmount), String.Format("{0:n}", paidammount), String.Format("{0:n}",change), thisDay.ToString("g"), discount.ToString());
            frmReceipt.ShowDialog();
```

> Set Parameters and Binding Source

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
namespace Pos
{
    public partial class FormReceipt : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {

        List<Receipt> _list;
        string _total, _cash, _change, _date, _user, _discount;
        public FormReceipt(List<Receipt> datasource, string total,string cash, string change, string date, string discount)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _list = datasource;
            _total = total;
            _cash = cash;
            _change = change;
            _date = date;
            _user = Sessiondata.user;
            _discount = discount;
        }

        private void FormReceipt_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReceiptBindingSource.DataSource = _list;
            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[] para = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[]{
            new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pTotal",_total),
            new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pCash",_cash),
            new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pChange",_change),
            new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pDate",_date),
            new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pUser",_user),
            new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pItems",_list.Count.ToString()),
            new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pDiscount",_discount+"%")
            };

            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(para);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();


        }

        private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am posting my code which is working fine as you want. Check this code and do the customization in the code as needed.

```
List<Receipt> _list;
    string _total, _cash, _change, _date, _user, _discount;
    public FormReceipt(List<Receipt> datasource, string total,string cash, string change, string date, string discount)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _list = datasource;
        _total = total;
        _cash = cash;
        _change = change;
        _date = date;
        _user = Sessiondata.user;
        _discount = discount;
    }

    private void FormReceipt_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReceiptBindingSource.DataSource = _list;
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[] para = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[]{
        new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pTotal",_total),
        new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pCash",_cash),
        new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pChange",_change),
        new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pDate",_date),
        new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pUser",_user),
        new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pItems",_list.Count.ToString()),
        new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pDiscount",_discount+"%")
        };

        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(para);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

             Export(ReportViewer1.LocalReport, false);
             Print();
             Dispose();
    }
private int m_currentPageIndex;
private IList<Stream> m_streams;
private Stream CreateStream(string name,
  string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding,
  string mimeType, bool willSeek)
  {
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    m_streams.Add(stream);
    return stream;
  }
    private void Export(LocalReport report, bool isLandscape)
    {
    string deviceInfo = string.Empty;
    if (isLandscape)
    {
        deviceInfo =
           @"<DeviceInfo>
            <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
            <PageWidth>11in</PageWidth>
            <PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight>
            <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>
            <MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft>
            <MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>
            <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>
        </DeviceInfo>";
    }
    else
    {
        deviceInfo =
        @"<DeviceInfo>
            <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
            <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>
            <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>
            <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>
            <MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft>
            <MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>
            <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>
        </DeviceInfo>";
    }
    Warning[] warnings;
    m_streams = new List<Stream>();

    // Create Report DataSource
    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();

    rds.Value = _list;

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

    report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
       out warnings);
    foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
        stream.Position = 0;
}
private void Print()
{
    PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings(); //set printer settings
    string printerName = settings.PrinterName; //use default printer name

    if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
        throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");
    PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();

    if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
    {

        Response.Write("<script>alert('" + printerName + "')</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
        m_currentPageIndex = 0;
        printDoc.Print();
    }

}
private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    Metafile pageImage = new
       Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);
    ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, ev.PageBounds);
    m_currentPageIndex++;
    ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);

}
public void Dispose()
{
    if (m_streams != null)
    {
        foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
            stream.Close();
        m_streams = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code to class and then call function  PrintToPrinter and pass reportviewer as parameter then report will print silently 
for more details :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms252091(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

```
    private static List<Stream> m_streams;
    private static int m_currentPageIndex = 0;
    static  LocalReport  report = new LocalReport();

    public static void PrintToPrinter(LocalReport report)
    {
        Export(report);

    }

    public static void Export(LocalReport report, bool print = true)
    {
        string deviceInfo =
        @"<DeviceInfo>
            <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
            <PageWidth>{pageSettings.PaperSize.Width * 100}in</PageWidth>
            <PageHeight>{pageSettings.PaperSize.Height * 100}in</PageHeight>
            <MarginTop>{pageSettings.Margins.Top * 100}in</MarginTop>
            <MarginLeft>{pageSettings.Margins.Left * 100}in</MarginLeft>
            <MarginRight>{pageSettings.Margins.Right * 100}in</MarginRight>
            <MarginBottom>{pageSettings.Margins.Bottom * 100}in</MarginBottom>
        </DeviceInfo>";
        Warning[] warnings;
        m_streams = new List<Stream>();
        report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);
        foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
            stream.Position = 0;

        if (print)
        {
            Print();
        }
    }


    public static void Print()
    {
        if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
        }
        else
        {
            printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
            m_currentPageIndex = 0;
            printDoc.Print();
        }
    }

    public static Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding, string mimeType, bool willSeek)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        m_streams.Add(stream);
        return stream;
    }

    public static void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        Metafile pageImage = new
           Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);

        // Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
        Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
            ev.PageBounds.Left - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
            ev.PageBounds.Top - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
            ev.PageBounds.Width,
            ev.PageBounds.Height);

        // Draw a white background for the report
        ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

        // Draw the report content
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);

        // Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.
        m_currentPageIndex++;
        ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
    }

    public static void DisposePrint()
    {
        if (m_streams != null)
        {
            foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                stream.Close();
            m_streams = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Refrain from adding code only answers. Please try explaining how your code solves the problem posted by OP.